# Java trying to connect to HDFS throws HADOOP_HOME unset, could not find winutils

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

I'm trying to prototype an app to use Hadoop as a datastore and I'm falling over at the first hurdle. I've got access to a Hadoop cluster and I purloined a test sample from Spring to try out the first baby step:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataInputStream;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataOutputStream;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.URI;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HdfsTest {

    @Test
    public void testHdfs() throws Exception {    

        System.setProperty("HADOOP_USER_NAME", "adam");

        // Path that we need to create in HDFS.
        // Just like Unix/Linux file systems, HDFS file system starts with "/"
        final Path path = new Path("/usr/adam/junk.txt");

        // Uses try with resources in order to avoid close calls on resources
        // Creates anonymous sub class of DistributedFileSystem to allow calling
        // initialize as DFS will not be usable otherwise
        try (
                final DistributedFileSystem dFS
                        = new DistributedFileSystem() {
                    {
                        initialize(new URI(
                                "hdfs://hanameservice/user/adam"),
                                new Configuration());
                    }
                };
                // Gets output stream for input path using DFS instance
                final FSDataOutputStream streamWriter = dFS.create(path);
                // Wraps output stream into PrintWriter to use high level
                // and sophisticated methods
                final PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(streamWriter);
                ) {
            // Writes tutorials information to file using print writer
            writer.println("bungalow bill");
            writer.println("what did you kill");
            System.out.println("File Written to HDFS successfully!");
        }
    }
```

These are the Hadoop libraries I'm using:

```xml
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-hdfs</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Could I be missing a dependency?

This is the logging with the errors - it seems there are 2 separate errors though.

```
2017-06-23 16:01:38.787  WARN   --- [           main] org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell             : Did not find winutils.exe: {}

java.io.FileNotFoundException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: HADOOP_HOME and hadoop.home.dir are unset. -see https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/WindowsProblems
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.fileNotFoundException(Shell.java:528)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.getHadoopHomeDir(Shell.java:549)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.getQualifiedBin(Shell.java:572)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.<clinit>(Shell.java:669)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.StringUtils.<clinit>(StringUtils.java:79)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getBoolean(Configuration.java:1445)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.initialize(FileSystem.java:221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.initialize(DistributedFileSystem.java:145)
    at com.bp.gis.tardis.HdfsTest$1.<init>(HdfsTest.java:34)
    at com.bp.gis.tardis.HdfsTest.testHdfs(HdfsTest.java:31)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:316)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:114)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.MethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(MethodTestDescriptor.java:171)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:40)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.MethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(MethodTestDescriptor.java:168)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.MethodTestDescriptor.execute(MethodTestDescriptor.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.MethodTestDescriptor.execute(MethodTestDescriptor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.lambda$execute$1(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:81)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SingleTestExecutor.executeSafely(SingleTestExecutor.java:66)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:76)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.lambda$execute$1(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:91)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SingleTestExecutor.executeSafely(SingleTestExecutor.java:66)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:76)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.lambda$execute$1(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:91)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SingleTestExecutor.executeSafely(SingleTestExecutor.java:66)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:76)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:43)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:87)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.Launcher.execute(Launcher.java:93)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:61)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:51)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: HADOOP_HOME and hadoop.home.dir are unset.
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.checkHadoopHomeInner(Shell.java:448)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.checkHadoopHome(Shell.java:419)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.<clinit>(Shell.java:496)
    ... 35 common frames omitted

2017-06-23 16:01:39.449  WARN   --- [           main] org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader  : Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.net.UnknownHostException: hanameservice

    at org.apache.hadoop.security.SecurityUtil.buildTokenService(SecurityUtil.java:418)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.NameNodeProxiesClient.createProxyWithClientProtocol(NameNodeProxiesClient.java:130)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:343)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:287)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.initialize(DistributedFileSystem.java:156)
    at com.bp.gis.tardis.HdfsTest$1.<init>(HdfsTest.java:34)
    at com.bp.gis.tardis.HdfsTest.testHdfs(HdfsTest.java:31)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:316)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:114)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.MethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(MethodTestDescriptor.java:171)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:40)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.MethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(MethodTestDescriptor.java:168)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.MethodTestDescriptor.execute(MethodTestDescriptor.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.MethodTestDescriptor.execute(MethodTestDescriptor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.lambda$execute$1(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:81)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SingleTestExecutor.executeSafely(SingleTestExecutor.java:66)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:76)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.lambda$execute$1(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:91)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SingleTestExecutor.executeSafely(SingleTestExecutor.java:66)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:76)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.lambda$execute$1(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:91)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SingleTestExecutor.executeSafely(SingleTestExecutor.java:66)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:76)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:43)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:87)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.Launcher.execute(Launcher.java:93)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:61)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:51)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: hanameservice
    ... 36 more
```

How do I sort this out? My contact person with the Hadoop cluster I'm trying to connect with is not familiar with the hdfs: protocol and their frame of reference seems to be all manual and not programmatic. They want me to login to an edge node and run scripts there in a shell. I feel I should be asking them particular questions, but I'm not sure what.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 distinct problems:

1. It appears you are running from a Windows host.  On Windows, Hadoop requires native code extensions so that it can integrate with the OS correctly for things like file access semantics and permissions.  Notice that the exception message contains a link to an Apache Hadoop wiki page: [WindowsProblems](https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/WindowsProblems).  That page contains information on how to handle this.
2. There is a failure to establish a socket connection to host "hanameservice".  This is most likely not a real name, but rather a logical name used for [HDFS High Availability](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HDFSHighAvailabilityWithQJM.html).  Internally, the HDFS client code would map this logical name to 1 of 2 real NameNode host names, but only if the configuration is complete.  You likely do not have a complete set of the configuration files (core-site.xml and hdfs-site.xml) from the cluster.  You would need the complete configuration on your local system for this to work.

> They want me to login to an edge node and run scripts there in a shell.

Overall, this may be the shortest path for you rather than trying to work through the Windows integration and configuration.  If you wrap your code in the Hadoop [`Tool`](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/util/Tool.html) interface, build it as a jar, and then copy that jar to the edge node, then you'll be able to run it as `hadoop jar your-app.jar`.  You'll be running inside a known working environment, with no need to sort out the native code extensions and no need to worry about whether or not configuration is complete and up-to-date with the cluster configuration.